# Android SQL exception

Tags: android, sqlite

My Logs is:

```
09-04 09:04:39.997  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-04 09:04:40.185  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
09-04 09:04:40.185  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 410: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
09-04 09:04:40.185  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-04 09:04:40.185  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
09-04 09:04:40.189  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 432: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
09-04 09:04:40.189  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-04 09:04:40.237  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
09-04 09:04:40.237  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 373: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
09-04 09:04:40.237  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-04 09:04:40.237  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
09-04 09:04:40.237  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 375: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
09-04 09:04:40.237  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-04 09:04:40.425  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
09-04 09:04:40.425  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb938abe0, tid 18653
09-04 09:04:40.465  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
09-04 09:04:40.465  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
09-04 09:04:40.665  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-04 09:04:40.701  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
09-04 09:04:40.713  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
09-04 09:04:40.757  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
09-04 09:04:40.769  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
09-04 09:04:40.769  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-04 09:04:46.777  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "productname": syntax error
09-04 09:04:46.781  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-04 09:04:46.781  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d5fb20)
09-04 09:04:46.789  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.yahya.sqlitesample, PID: 18653
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "productname": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE products(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT productname TEXT );
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
            at com.example.yahya.sqlitesample.MyDBHandler.onCreate(MyDBHandler.java:34)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at com.example.yahya.sqlitesample.MyDBHandler.addProduct(MyDBHandler.java:49)
            at com.example.yahya.sqlitesample.MainActivity.addButtonClicked(MainActivity.java:33)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 09:04:46.797  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 240K, 9% free 3282K/3576K, paused 5ms, total 6ms
09-04 09:04:50.669  18653-18653/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 18653 SIG: 9
```

MyDBHandler:

```
package com.example.yahya.sqlitesample;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION  = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME  = "products.db";
    public  static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
    public  static final String COLUMN_ID  = "_id";
    public  static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
                COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP  TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Add a new item to the db
    public void addProduct(Products product)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        db.close();

    }

    //Delete a product from db
    public void deleteProduct(String name)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "=\"" + name + "\";");
    }

    //Print out the database as String
    public String dbToString()
    {
        String dbString  = new String();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        while(!c.isAfterLast())
        {
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"))!=null)
            {
                dbString += c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("productname")));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
        }

        db.close();
        return dbString;

    }

}
```

The Main activity class is:

```
package com.example.yahya.sqlitesample;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    EditText yTextInout;
    TextView yTextView;
    MyDBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        yTextInout = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yText);
        yTextView   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ytextView);
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this,null, null, 1);
        printDataBase();
    }

    public void addButtonClicked(View view)
    {
          Products product = new Products(yTextInout.toString());
         dbHandler.addProduct(product);
         printDataBase();
    }

    public void deleteButtonClicked(View view)
    {
        String productName = yTextInout.getText().toString();
        dbHandler.deleteProduct(productName);
       // printDataBase();
    }

    public void printDataBase()
    {
        String dbString = dbHandler.dbToString();
        yTextView.setText(dbString);
        yTextInout.setText("");
    }



}
```

The products class:

```
package com.example.yahya.sqlitesample;

/**
 * Created by Yahya on 9/3/2015.
 */
public class Products
{
    private int _id;
    private String _productname;

    public Products()
    {

    }

    public Products(String productName)
    {
        this._productname = productName;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id)
    {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public void set_productname(String _productName)
    {
        this._productname = _productName;
    }

    public int get_id()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public String get_productname()
    {
        return _productname;
    }
}
```

and the activity_main.xml:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/yText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:id="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/yText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/yText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/yText"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:onClick="addButtonClicked" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/yText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/yText"
    android:onClick="deleteButtonClicked" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/ytextView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/addButton" />
```

When I want to run my code, it makes an exception and quits the program with unfortunately the  hass been stopped. 
Please help me to fix the exception.

Comment: forgot to add `,` separator between column names

Comment: I would recommend to use some orm instead of writing direct sql code, for example ormlite is good start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Finally I fixed my problem, there where 3 things:

1- In MyDBHandler class, a comma should be inserted right after the name of the columns, as Pavan suggested:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
                ");";
```

2- The second issue was in my addButtonClicked function (in the main activity) where I used the following by mistake:

```
yTextInput.toString();
```

and I had to use the following instead:

```
yTextInput.getText().toString();
```

3- And finally the most important one in the dbToString function (MyDBHandler class), I did not move the cursor in the while, so the while continued for ever. I used c.moveToNext for this purpose.

```
        while(!c.isAfterLast())
    {
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"))!=null)
        {
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
```

Well actually I used the New Boston tutorial for improving my android coding. Many thanks to Bucky Robert for his fantastic tutorials but it sometimes has such bugs in the coding of tutorial which causes a pain in neck! (and took me 3 days to solve it).

Answer (score 2):

check this line
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "productname": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE products(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT productname TEXT );

you have syntax error in above just put , after first column name and check

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
                ");";
```

Comment: I did this, the app runs without exception but nothing is shown in the genymotion and just an infinite logs are shown, followings are just a slice of that:
09-04 09:27:50.361    2259-2259/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 293K, 27% free 3907K/5284K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
09-04 09:27:50.369    2259-2259/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 734K, 35% free 3467K/5284K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
09-04 09:27:50.377    2259-2259/com.example.yahya.sqlitesample D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 29% free 3761K/5284K, paused 3ms, total 3ms

Comment: do one thing debug your app on your button click where you communicating with database

Comment: to inserting breakpoints in your functions check this 
android studio https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html
eclipse http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html

Comment: I cannot debug it, nothing is shown in the debug tab.